# How to make a select with the "childrens" on a Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created an Single Table Inheritance entity called Source. It has a lot of specific childrens (types). For example MonsterSource, IndeedSource, FooSource...

```
class Source < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :job_offers
    def process
        puts 'Process from Source'
    end
end

class MonsterSource < Source
end

class FooSource < Source
end
```

In my edit view from a Source, I want to create a Select that contains all the "childrens" (types) of this Source. For example, I want, when editing a Source, to choose between "Monster Source, Indeed Source and Foo Source" from a select button.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Source class:

```
def self.types
 ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |klass| klass < self }
end
```

Then in your view:

```
 <%= select_tag :source_type, options_for_select(Source.types) %>
```

Comment: Man. Thank you. Work like a charm